# How to define a group of related variables in Python?

Tags: python

In JavaScript, I like to define my variables in objects so that it is clear (to me, at least) that all of it's properties are related.

For example:

```
var box = {
  width: 100,
  height: 200,
  weight: 80
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grouping using the dictionary is only one of the ways to do it. If you like `a.b` attribute access syntax more, you could use one of the following:

### Module

You could do it using the module, for example put them to something named `settings.py`:

```
width = 100
height = 200
weight = 80
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
import settings
area = settings.width * settings.height
```

But modules in Python are singletons, so if you change `settings.width` in one place - it will change in all the others.

### Class

Also you could do grouping using class attributes:

```
class Box:
    width = 100
    height = 200
    weight = 80

print(Box.width) # 100

# You could use instances to update attributes on separate instance
box = Box()
print(box.width) # 100
box.width = 10
print(box.width) # 10

# But their original values will still be saved on class attributes
print(Box.width) # 100
```

### namedtuple

Another option is to use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
from collections import namedtuple

Box = namedtuple('Box', ('width', 'height', 'weight'))
box = Box(100, 200, 80)
print(box.width) # 100

# Tuples are immutable, so this is more like a way to group constants
box.width = 10 # AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 8):

This is called a dict or dictionary in python
the syntax is almost identical:

```
box = {
  'width': 100,
  'height': 200,
  'weight': 80
}
```

you can later access these values like this:

```
box['width']
```

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is the lookup cost in indexing the string key vs. having plain variables. I wouldn't recommend this approach in performance sensitive areas of your code.

Comment: @ErikUggeldahl, Thank you for pointing that out.  For the script I am currently working on, performance is not going to be an issue.  I am curious if the performance cost is higher than in JavaScript.  Do you know if they are similar?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah According to this article, the dot (.) notation for lookup in Javascript is simply a syntax sugar over a string lookup. In both cases they should be performing roughly equivalent operations of string comparison and value retrieval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

In terms of real world performance, that's a much more difficult question as it will vary widely depending on your interpreter (e.g. V8 vs. CPython).